# Retrofit change multipart entries Content-Type

Tags: retrofit, content-type, multipart

I'm using Retrofit 2, and I have following method in my service:

```
@Multipart
@POST("avatar.ashx")
Call<ResponseBody> getAvatar(@Header("Authorization") String auth,
                             @Part(value = "l", encoding = "8bit") String login,
                             @Part(value = "p", encoding = "8bit") String password);
```

The server is expecting request with parts with

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

But what retrofit produces in request is

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

Is there any way to change the Content-Type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe someone needs that, so I will post workaround I've found:
Method in my service:

```
    @Multipart
    @POST("avatar.ashx")
    Call<ResponseBody> getAvatar(@Header("Authorization") String auth,
                             @PartMap() Map<String, RequestBody> requestData);
```

And usage of the method:

```
    LinkedHashMap<String, RequestBody> requestData = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    RequestBody rb;
    rb = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), getSettings().getUserName());
    requestData.put("l", rb);
    rb = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), getSettings().getPassword());
    requestData.put("p", rb);
    mCall = getAvatarApiService().getAvatar(auth, requestData);
```